# Flickr API returns duplicate photos

Tags: python, flickr

I'm trying to extract geo-tagged photos using by python from Flickr API.
But, it returns duplicate photos.
when it extracting over 41 pages, returns same photo URL.
Here is my code,

```
# !/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
from flickrapi import FlickrAPI
import json, time, os
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db = client.flickr
coll = db.flickr_a

API_KEY = "xxx"
SEACRET_KEY = "xxx" 

flickr = FlickrAPI(API_KEY, SEACRET_KEY, format="parsed-json")
extras="url_c,url_l,url_o,geo,date_taken,owner_name"

for page in xrange(1,550):
    disney = flickr.photos.search(bbox="139.867,35.613,139.914,35.645", 
per_page=100,extras=extras,page=page)
    photos = disney["photos"]
    coll.insert(photos)
```

Please give me advice or sample code.
Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I edited your post, so your credentials (api key and secret) are not shown anymore. Next time please remove them before, you REALLY don't want to share them (that's why it's called a "secret")

Comment: I do not know Flickr, but usually you can login into your account and remove/add new api keys and secrets. Maybe you want to delete that one you posted and create a new one.

Comment: @ user3079834 Thanks editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to store the photo urls in a python list and remove duplicates by turning it into a set.

at the beginning

```
coll = []
```

to add

```
coll.append(photos)
```

and at the end (I'm guessing your insert command here)

```
for p in set(coll):
    db.flickr_a.insert(p)
```